# good analysis book forself-study

Tags: real-analysis, book-recommendation

As I have to study Analysis(against my liking)(see my previous post) now ,I am wondering what would a good book for me to start with?

I have a basic knowledge about analysis although not so thorough

I know sequences,basic definitions(limit points,closed,open etc),continuity ,differentiability etc.

So what will be a good book for me to start i.e looking for a book just one level above being an introductory textbook

Comment: You can use Bartle and Sherbet. And as you get more advanced, Rudin is a good clear book!

Comment: This is an excellent book:

http://smile.amazon.com/Elementary-Analysis-Calculus-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/1461462703/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1428429642&sr=1-1&keywords=analysis+ross

but maybe you're looking for something more advanced.  If Ross is too easy for you then you should definitely read baby Rudin:

http://smile.amazon.com/Principles-Mathematical-Analysis-International-Mathematics/dp/007054235X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1428429703&sr=8-1&keywords=ruden+analysis

Comment: I second Bartle and Sherbet. Carothers, as well as Stein and Shakarchi are two other good books not yet mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was a student I was exposed to mathematical analysis thru the book *Principles of mathematical analysis* by Walter Rudin. I must say that I loved it and I then became a working mathematician in the field of analysis also in view of that book. However I know that many students simply hate Rudin's book because it has no image at all, almost no examples, and only hard problems.
Therefore I usually suggest Charles Pugh's book on Real Analysis (published by Springer-Verlag), a more gentle introduction to real analysis. I also like Tom Apostol's book on mathematical analysis (**not** calculus!), but it may be hard to find nowadays.

Comment: would surely look into this book +1

Answer (score 1):

If you had already done calculus, I would surely recommend Zorich.

The explanations are pretty concrete (Later some things get abstract but not early on) and it has real-life examples and applications as well as some "intuitive" explanations.

Now, I have to admit that I have not found the exercises easy. Some are false (as in he states a wrong exercise), but those are rare, and some are really difficult. I also found some problem early on which solution uses multidimensional material before he even covered such material. Thus, you can easily see that the exercises need work.

I recommend you read the two volumes of Zorich WITHOUT solving exercises, then move on to Baby Rudin and solve the exercises there as well.

Good luck.